# How to show two custom pages at a same time (Silent installation of some exe's and Progress bar) in NSIS

Tags: windows-installer, nsis

I'm new to NSIS.
I'm currently working on one installer which is having two options

1. Express installation: All the 3rd party tools required for our software are installing silently in 
   background, at the same time i need to show one progress bar in the foreground
2. Custom installation: Normal installation

Please anyone help me to resolve 1st step (Express installation)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: NSIS does not really support that (but you can hack it to do it). Maybe use MSI instead?

Comment: Can't we  use BgWorker (For performing parallel tasks)

Comment: [link](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/BgWorker_plug-in)

Comment: You don't need BgWorker, you should execute the installers with ExecWait in a section.

Comment: Ya i'm executing the 3rd party software's by using the command
**ExecWait '"msiexec" /i "$INSTDIR\software1\software1.msi" /quiet**


So software1 will be installing silently (It will take max 1 or 2 min depending the system speed), 

My question is "How to add Progress bar while software1 is installing silently" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a balloon pop up message in the Notification Area while your installer is running: https://nsis.sourceforge.io/NotifyIcon_plug-in

The example of such usage you can take from here: https://sourceforge.net/p/nsisplus/NsisSetupLib/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/notify.nsi

Comment: I'm installing all the 3rd party software's via batch file and while executing batch file i'm adding a progress bar by using

Comment: RealProgress::GradualProgress /NOUNLOAD 1 5 25
Sleep 20000

RealProgressBar plugin